# Buttons of different size sharing the same drawable as background

Tags: android

My application has a big button with an oval shape as background, it is runtime created. Let's name this button A.

When I enable some function the visibility of A is set to GONE, and four smaller buttons are shown, with the same background of A.

When I hide the buttons and show A again, it has proper size, but the background drawable is still of the size of the smaller buttons previously drawn. How can i resize it so that it fills the size of the A button?

**Update:** My code

```
//BigButton.java
//...
GradientDrawable idle = new GradientDrawable();
idle.setColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
idle.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
idle.setStroke(2, Color.rgb(red2, green2, blue2));
btn.setWidth(50*3f);
btn.setHeight(65*3f);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(idle);
//...

//ChildButton.java
//...
GradientDrawable idle = BigButton.this.getIdleDrawable();
btn2.setWidth(50);
btn2.setHeight(65);
btn2.setBackgroundDrawable(idle);
//...
```

**Update2:** The following creates a new drawable so that there's no resource sharing between parent and child buttons.

```
GradientDrawable idle = (GradientDrawable) ButtonSetupPanel.this.caller.getIdle().getConstantState().newDrawable();
```

Comment: Post the xml you're using and any code you're using to set the backgrounds.

Comment: As said the Drawable is runtime created, so I have no XML for the Shape. It looks like when a new view is created, then the drawable resizes itself, so if i show again the big button it is shown with small resized drawable, and I'd need a way to refresh its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same reference for both buttons.  Use two different references, but with the same settings.  This way changes to the drawable for the small button won't be visible on the big and vice versa.

Comment: Isn't there a way to "refresh" the drawable so that I don't have to use two different ones?

Comment: No, because they're looking at the same object for the drawable.  If you don't want changes by one of them being picked up by the others, they need to be separate objects.